# What’s the best way to patch drywall with wood paneling or another ceiling behind it?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, patch

I removed a closet from this room and found wood paneling behind the wall and more ceiling above the ceiling. I’m wondering what the best way to patch it would be.

Can I just screw the drywall patches into the layers behind? Do I need special screws? Or should I cut out the exposed substrate and screw it to wooden shims mounted behind the wall?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: area in need of drywall patching]

Comment: On the walls that looks like wood studs so drywall screws are used.  Not sure about the ceiling, if it is cement or or drywall with a texture finish.  Will need to try to push a nail in.  If cement then construction adhesive should hold those small pieces needed.  Tape and mud the edges and feather the mud out to smooth it out.

Comment: +1 on plain old screws fastening strips of drywall to the wall.  On the ceiling, maybe glue with whatever you can use to keep it there while the glue cures?  If screws will hold the drywall in place, use screws.  If not, worst case, jack up some boards to keep the drywall in place.

Comment: Be cautious of that old ceiling layer as it looks like a popcorn ceiling which may contain asbestos. If you can locate the ceiling joists/bottom chord of the trusses, it would be best to attach any ceiling board to some solid framing. Screws into old drywall may end up pulling back out over time and lead to cracking. It may help to try to remove the piece in the corner there and fill in an entire rectangle rather than just strips as well.

Answer (score 1):

An adhesive like a bead of caulk or construction adhesive should do the trick. Then place your new drywall onto it.

Make sure to follow up with some drywall screws while the adhesive is still wet. Honestly, you could probably forgo the adhesive.

This applies to both the ceiling and wall.

Comment: You may not need adhesive. I'd just hold it in place until the first screw was driven, then let that support it while driving the others.

Comment: You can’t see it in this picture, but it’s definitely wood paneling and not studs. It’s only about half-an-inch thick and doesn’t go all the way to the floor. Does that change any of this advice?

Comment: @TracerBullet Nope. It just makes my first sentence irrelevant. I corrected my answer to reflect that.